# How can I toggle the style of a paragraph using [ngStyle] and ternary on Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular. I try to toggle the paragraph using a method. I declared two variables that contain my object for the style of my paragraph. My problem is I got an error

```
Error: src/app/directives-sample/directives-sample.component.html:6:7 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [klass: string]: any; }'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [klass: string]: any; }'.

6 <div [ngStyle]="!isSpecial ? 'currentStyles' : ''">
        ~~~~~~~

  src/app/directives-sample/directives-sample.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './directives-sample.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component DirectivesSampleComponent.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.
```

Here's my code:

//html

```
<div [ngStyle]="isSpecial ? 'currentStyles' : 'specialStyles'">
    This div is initially italic, normal weight, and extra large (24px).
</div>
```

//ts

```
export class DirectivesSampleComponent implements OnInit {
  isSpecial: boolean = false;
  currentStyles = { 'font-style':'italic','font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': '24px', 'color': 'red'};
  specialStyles = { 'font-style':'italic','font-weight': 'italic', 'font-size': '16px', 'color': 'blue'};
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggleSpecial() {
    this.isSpecial = !this.isSpecial;
  }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [ngStyle]="isSpecial ? currentStyles: specialStyles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make use of ngClass instead of ngStyle and you can begin by creating your 2 style classes like below:

```
.currentStyles {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red
}

.specialStyles {
  font-weight: italic;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: blue
}
```

Then in your paragraph, you can have the following:

```
<div [ngClass]="isSpecial ? 'specialStyles' : 'currentStyles'">
    This div is initially italic, normal weight, and extra large (24px).
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are providing value to [ngStyle] is incorrect.

Check: [angular doc for NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Correct way could be to provide specialStyles & currentStyles as is and not as string:

```
[ngStyle]="!isSpecial ? currentStyles : specialStyles"
```

Comment: You are not right, you are using `[ngStyle]` instead of `[ngClass]`

Comment: @Johnys currentStyles  & specialStyles are not css classes instead they are declared as properties in DirectivesSampleComponent  class

Comment: but this is not the way to do it, i dont think it works like that. The error is stating that you cannot put an array of strings into the argument.

Comment: Error says Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [klass: string]: any; }'. So the way it is implemented is incorrect: : <div [ngStyle]="isSpecial ? 'currentStyles' : 'specialStyles'"> this will not work